# Error when initializing the local directory as a Git repository

Tags: git, github

I have an existing repository on GitHub.  It's private, so I'm sorry I can't provide the URL as part of this question.  I have some code in a folder.  This folder does not have a .git folder.  I want to "connect" or "link" this folder with a remote repository.  I'm using [this documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/github/importing-your-projects-to-github/adding-an-existing-project-to-github-using-the-command-line).

Everything goes fine up to step 4.  Then I get this error:

```
% git init -b main
error: unknown switch `b'
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: What the result of :Git --version?

Comment: I'm asking because -b was added from git version 2.28....

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+%22git+init+-b%22

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could just go with this:

```
# Initialize a git repo on current folder
git init .

# Stage all objects in current folder (including subfolders)
git add .

# Commit git changes
git commit -m "First Commit"

# Add a Remote Git Repo
git remote add origin https://github.com/xxxx

# Finally push changes from local repo to remote repo
git push origin main
```